# owl carousel is not working with Angular 7

Tags: owl-carousel, angular7

owl carousel is not working when apply `*ngFor` loop in angular while it's working fine when apply static data.

```
<div id="regular">
      <div  *ngFor="let banner of slider" class="item">
          <div class="container padding-top-3x">
            <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 padding-bottom-2x text-md-left text-center">
                <div class="from-bottom"><img class="d-inline-block w-150 mb-4" src={{banner.logo.url}} alt="Puma">
                  <div class="h2 text-body mb-2 pt-1">{{banner.text1}}</div>

                  <div class="h2 text-body mb-4 pb-1">{{banner.text2}} <span class="text-medium">{{banner.price}}</span></div>
                </div><a class="btn btn-primary scale-up delay-1" href={{banner.hyperlink}}>View Offers&nbsp;<i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 padding-bottom-2x mb-3"><img class="d-block mx-auto" src="{{banner.file.url}}" alt="Puma Backpack"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </owl-carousel>
```

Comment: I have fixed this type of with the help of jquery. Refer to this URL.https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/2608

Answer (score 0):

You might have found the solution but I put the answer for the sake of others.
In Angular 6/7 use the new package "ngx-owl-carousel-o", more info [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel-o). Be reminded the old package isn't supported anymore.

In short, the Owl team has created a new package to support newer features in Angular thus a new package come. However, the base concept behind is the same and shouldn't create a problem implementing like earlier versions of Angular.

The mark-up has changed like this:

```html
<owl-carousel-o [options]="customOptions">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <ng-template carouselSlide [id]="post.Id" [width]="post.Image.Width">
      <img [src]="post.Image.Url" [alt]="" >
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</owl-carousel-o>
```

The [options] attribute is defined in the TypeScript file, my suggestion use a separate component for the Owl Carousel.

The official link mentioned above is well documented and descriptive. Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: I am using owl-carousel-o in angular 9, but responsive options are not working proper when I am using with*ngFor loop, whereas with static data it works normal. So can you please let me know how can I use responsive option with *ngFor loop?